# Mysql row is empty when I update json value in the row

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to update a json value in mysql. But I notice It delete de Old value in the row.

```
$image = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE ext = $user_id"));
$where = array('custo' => $image);
$dataOld = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT custom FROM users1 WHERE ext1 = $where"));
$dataOld = json_decode($dataOld, true);
$dataOld["2"]["value"] = "four";
$dataOld = json_encode($dataOld);
$data  = array('customFields' => $dataOld);
$wpdb->update($wpdb->prefix . 'kings', $data, $where);
```

I have a json like this in sql:

```
{"1":{"label":"empo","value":""},"2":{"label":"Comp","value":"A"}}
```

Instead of update "value" it prints

```
{"2":{"value":"four"}}
```

I am trying to get this:

```
{"1":{"label":"empo","value":""},"2":{"label":"Comp","value":"four"}}
```

Update:

```
$image = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE ext = $user_id"));
$where = array('custo' => $image);
$dataOld = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT custom FROM users1 WHERE ext1 = (SELECT id FROM users WHERE ext = $user_id)"));
$dataOld = json_decode($dataOld, true);
$dataOld["2"]["value"] = "four";
$dataOld = json_encode($dataOld);
$data  = array('customFields' => $dataOld);
$wpdb->update($wpdb->prefix . 'kings', $data, $where);
```

Comment: I don’t see you _decoding_ the JSON value you just read from the database?

Comment: Sorry, I missing a line. The code is now updated. Now you can check it. THX

Comment: Can’t really reproduce that, https://3v4l.org/aj4qk You’ll need to do a bit more debugging, and figure out where it actually goes wrong. Did you make a debug output of the modified value, before you execute the update?

Comment: Then should be for `$wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare` because If I dont update the json, the json is returned empty, when the row has a json.

Comment: The way you are trying to create that WHERE clause there is wrong, you can not concatenate an array into a string value, that will only result in the _text_ “Array” at this point.

Comment: Yes! THX! I changed the WHERE clause as `SELECT id FROM users WHERE ext = $user_id`. Now its perfect!

Comment: I have a new issue. I am targeting multiple rows with `$where`, how can I target 1 row. I am trying to use `ORDER BY appo DESC LIMIT 1` but I dont know how use it with  `$where`

Comment: You just need to add it to the end of your query, where is the problem?

Comment: I dont know how put it inside `$wpdb->update($wpdb->prefix . 'kings', $data, $where);` Should be inside `$where`, but its an array.

Comment: Ah, you are talking about the UPDATE part. Using ORDER BY and LIMIT in there doesn’t make much sense to begin with. This is the place where you _should_ be using an array again, $where here should be an array of column name => value pairs.

Comment: Ok. But in `$where = array('custo' => $image);` the column  `custo` Its not in table `id`. Thats why I dont know how insert `ORDER BY appo DESC LIMIT 1`. `custo` is from table `users1`

Comment: Stop talking about order by and limit, that is the wrong approach to begin with. What exactly are the criteria that determine, which record in the “kings” table you want to update?

Comment: Should be a column called `appo` ordered DESC. So i will edit the first result in column `custo`

Comment: Ordering has little to do with _explicitly_ identifying a specific record. If `WHERE ext1 = [subselect]` was what helped you _select_ this one(?) specific record in the first place - well then use an according WHERE clause (via array, filled accordingly), that demands that same value for `ext1`, as that subselect returned, for your UPDATE.